# composition sum of functions/sum of composition of functions

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I know it sounds really dumb, but is it true that $(f_1+f_2)\circ g=f_1\circ g+f_2\circ g$?

I know it must be really elementary, but I don't recall seeing this being proved (or defined) explicitly.

Comment: Not much to prove: $(f_1+f_2)(x)=f_1(x)+f_2(x)$, so $(f_1+f_2)(g(x))=f_1(g(x))+f_2(g(x))$.

Comment: Yes, this formula works, but the one with the addition on the right doesn’t. In this sense, there *is* something to prove, and @Semiclassical has done it.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)=f_{1}(x)+f_{2}(x)$. Since $$(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))=f_{1}(g(x))+f_{2}(g(x))=(f_{1}\circ g)(x)+(f_{2}\circ g)(x).$$
Thus
$$
f\circ g = (f_{1}+f_{2})\circ g = f_{1}\circ g+f_{2}\circ g.$$